# Ridge fit is not orthogonal to ridge residuals

Tags: regression, estimation, ridge-regression

So I'm reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09169.pdf on ridge regression. On page 8 under Example 1.3 it says

> From the figure it is obvious that for any $\lambda >0$ the ‘ridge fit’ $\widehat{Y}(\lambda)=X(X^{\top}X+\lambda I_p)^{-1}X^{\top}Y$ is not orthogonal to the observation $Y$. In other words, the ‘ridge residuals’ $Y − \widehat{Y}(\lambda)=(I_p-X(X^{\top}X+\lambda I_p)^{-1}X^{\top})Y$ are not orthogonal to the fit $\widehat{Y}(\lambda)$.

However my linear algebra is quite rusty. Does that mean that $\langle \widehat{Y}(\lambda),  Y− \widehat{Y}(\lambda)\rangle=0$ or are they refering to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. In the case of ordinary lieast squares (OLS),
$Y - \hat{Y} = (I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')Y$ and the fact that

$$(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')X = 0$$

implies that $Y - \hat{Y}$ is orthogonal to any linear combination of the $X$ (and hence to  $\hat{Y} = X\hat{\beta}$). However, it is no longer true that

$$(I-X(X'X+ \lambda I)^{-1}X')X = 0$$

so orthogonality to $\hat{Y}(\lambda)$ cannot be asserted of ridge residuals.

Comment: Okay so it is enough to show that $Y-\widehat{Y}(\lambda)$ is not orthogonal to $X$ since $\widehat{Y}(\lambda)$ is a linear combination of $X$?

Comment: Right. $\hat{Y}(\lambda)$  is indeed in the linear space spanned by the columns of $X$.